# How can I make a layout background flashing in android

Tags: android, layout, background

i want to make a layout background without ontouch method, to change colors every 1 second without ever stopping until back button is pressed like red white green, red white green etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider using PostDelayed ()?

```
public class MyView implements Runnable
{
  public void MyInit ()
  {
    ... set initial background ...
    postDelayed (this, 1000);  // delay a second - cause "run" to execute in 1 sec.
  }

  public void run()
  {
    ... toggle background ...
    postDelayed (this, 1000); // delay another second
  }
}
```

Comment: i a newbie so.. can u please give a complete example?

Comment: No, I can answer specific questions but, sorry, I'm not going to write the whole thing.

Comment: I modified my example; it now shows how you start the initial delay and then keep repeating.

Comment: that's quite a useful code as well,sorry for the trouble

Comment: Great!  If you have other specific questions, be sure to post them.  Although, please search the forum first to see if your question is already answered.

Answer (score 1):

You could changeBackground with Java Code [View.setBackground(int color)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29), then use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for changingBackground depending on result of `new Date().getTime()%3`.

For example, something like that will work :

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      int color = Color.RED;
      switch(new Date().getTime()%3){
         case 0:
            color = Color.RED;
            break;
         case 1:
            color = Color.WHITE;
            break;
         case 2:
            color = Color.GREEN;
            break;

      }
      yourView.setBackground(color);
      handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
   }
};

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

Comment: how should i define date?

Comment: What do you mean ? Date is already defined when you instantiates a new Date to the current one.

Comment: sorry my mistake, mixed with another thing